# Can I have more than one child content type for a book content type?

Tags: 8, nodes

I have two content type I selected as book content type: Text_book_type and audio_book_type.

Now, I need that these content have different child content type:

chapter_type for text_book_type and audio_chapter_type for audio_book_type.

Is there a way in Drupal 8 to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create two different Content types for your chapter nodes, just like you have different Content types for your book nodes.

The "Parent-Child" relationship you describe is usually accomplished with Entity references.

Add Entity reference fields to your chapter_type and audio_chapter-type and configure them to reference text_book_type and audio_book_type nodes respectively.

Then when creating a chapter node you'll be able to choose which book node it belongs to.

You can use Views to list all child nodes on a book page through that reference field, if you need such a list.